# Logarithmic approximation of $\sum_0^{N-1} \frac{1}{2i + 1}$

Tags: summation, logarithms

Can anyone confirm that it's possible to approximate the sum $\sum_0^{N-1} \frac{1}{2i + 1}$ with the $\frac{\log{N}}{2}$? And why?

It's clearly visible that the sum has a logarithmic growth over `i` (check [wolphram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%282%2ai%2B+1%29%2C+i+from+0+to+N-1)) but it's unclear to me how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over 2i + 1}&=\half\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over i + 1/2}
=
\half\bracks{\Psi\pars{\half + N} - \Psi\pars{\half}}
=
\half\Psi\pars{N + \half} + \half\,\gamma + \ln\pars{2}
\end{align}
where $\Psi\pars{z}$ is the $\it\mbox{digamma function}$ and
$\gamma = 0.577215664901533\ldots$ is the $\it\mbox{Euler-Mascheroni constant}$.
$\ds{\Psi\pars{1 \over 2} = -\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}}$

Also,
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \approx \ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z}\ \mbox{when}\ \verts{z} \gg 1}$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over 2i + 1}
&\approx
\half\bracks{\ln\pars{N + \half} - {1 \over 2\pars{N + 1/2}}} + \half\,\gamma + \ln\pars{2}\,,
\qquad N \gg 1
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over 2i + 1}
\approx
\half\ln\pars{N + \half} - {1 \over 2\pars{2N + 1}} + \half\,\gamma + \ln\pars{2}\,,
\quad N \gg 1}
$$
$\large{\bf ADDENDUM:}$ Following $\tt @Matteo$ comment:

> Also,
> \begin{align}
> \half\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over i + 1/2}
> &=\half\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}\pars{{1 \over i + 1/2} - {1 \over i + 1}}
> + \half\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over i + 1} - \ln\pars{N}} + \half\,\ln\pars{N}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over \pars{i + 1}\pars{i + 1/2}}
> + \half\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over i + 1} - \ln\pars{N}} + \half\,\ln\pars{N}
> \\[3mm]&\stackrel{N\ \gg\ 1}{\ds{\LARGE\sim}}
> {1 \over 4}\,{\Psi\pars{1} - \Psi\pars{1/2} \over 1 - 1/2} + \half\,\gamma
> + \half\,\ln\pars{N}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \half\braces{-\gamma - \bracks{-\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}}} + \half\,\gamma
> + \half\,\ln\pars{N}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#0000ff}{\large\half\,\ln\pars{N + \half} - {1 \over 2\pars{2N + 1}} + \half\,\gamma + \ln\pars{2}}
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}+
> \color{#ff0000}{\underbrace{\half\bracks{%
> {1 \over 2N + 1} - \ln\pars{1 + {1 \over 2N}}}}
> _{\sim\ {\rm O}\pars{1/N^{2}}}}
> \end{align}

Comment: I suppose that you have a typo in the last (blue) equation : 2(N+1/2) = (2N+1) and not 2(2N+1). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There is an extra factor $2$ due to the $1/2$ factor in front of the previous bracket $[]$.

Comment: Oooops ! Sorry for that stupidity ! Cheers.

Comment: Felix, could you please explain me the passage from summation to digamma function? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Matteo I found that expression in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik Table ( 7$^{\underline{\rm a}}$ ed. page 904. Formula ${\bf 8.365}.3$ ). It's exactly written in the form $\displaystyle{\large\Psi\left(x + n\right) = \Psi\left(x\right) + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over x + k}}$. However, I'll put and ADDENDUM to the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the follow up, I'll try to make my way through it!Ciao!

Answer (score 2):

This is a Riemann sum for the integral from 0 to $N$ of $1/(2x+1)$, so it approximates $(1/2)\ln(2N+1)$, which is approximately $(1/2)\ln N$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Could you please explain also why the Riemann sum approximates $(1/2)\ln(2N+1)$?

Comment: Because that is the solution to the integral, and Riemann sums always approximate the actual integral. The Euler-Mascheroni constant indirectly measures how close this particular sum is (you should look it up on Wikipedia, it is very interesting).